# Missing "AWS Toolkit for Eclipse"

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse to work.  I downloaded Eclipse 4.5.0 Mars (Java EE edition), then followed these instructions from Amazon's website (https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/).

Problem is, in Step 3, it says to select "AWS Toolkit for Eclipse".  But clearly, it's not an option.  Is there something I skipped, or Amazon's documentation is just out of date?  Thanks everyone!

> 1. Install the Toolkit Open Help → Install New Software….
> 2. Enter http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse in the text box labeled “Work with” at the top of the dialog.
> 3. Select “AWS Toolkit for Eclipse” from the list below.
> 4. Click “Next.” Eclipse guides you through the remaining installation steps. Note: The toolkit requires Eclipse 3.6 or higher.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices you are shown is a Tree, by default just the top level categories are shown. Expand the tree to see all the choices:
[image]

It looks like 'AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core' is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  But how come the documentation doesn't keep up with the product changes?  For a developer platform, that's very important to do.  Thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't provide AWS SDK for java.